# Sending event handlers as props into a React component using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following code for a React component. What's the right way to declare the two `onClick` handlers passed into the component?

```
interface LoginFormProps {
    loginClicked: ???? <--- onClick handler signature
    cancelClicked: ???? <--- onClick handler signature
}

class LoginForm extends React.Component<LoginFormProps, {}> {
    render() {
        <form>
            <button onClick={loginClicked}>
                Login
            </button>
            <button onClick={cancelClicked}>
                Cancel
            </button>
        </form>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I typically use:

```
interface ILoginFormProps {
    loginClicked: (ev) => void;
    //
}
```

But if you want to be really strict about your typing:

```
interface ILoginFormProps {
    loginClicked: (ev: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => void;
    //
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Cristi. That works very well!

Comment: More brief: `loginClicked: React.MouseEventHandler`

Comment: I had gone through many tutorials, each wanting me to create a brand new project, to stumble here and get the most straightforward answer. Thank you!